# Sheets protect command error

Tags: excel, vba

I have an existing workbook with 2 visible sheets. The first sheet has a button users can click to update the data on sheet 2 (which is a sharepoint list that updates automatically).

The ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll method worked initially, but now that my workbook is being distributed outside of it's initial scope I need to be able to protect it (while still allowing users to refresh data)

Since the Activeworkbook.RefreshAll will not work while the target sheet is protected  I considered using the following:

```
Sub RefreshDataSheet

Sheets("Data").Unprotect
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Sheets("Data").Protect

End Sub
```

Where "Data" is the name of sheet with the updated list. This attempt still returns the error that "The cell or chart that you are trying to change is protected and therefore read-only."

Does anyone have experience with this? Typically the unprotect then protect strategy works for me - what am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does your list refresh in the background? If so, you need to turn that off so that the Protect line doesn't run until the refresh has finished.

Answer (score 0):

`RefreshAll` is an asynchronous command (more info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838648.aspx).  Basically, it will keep running and return control to the caller before it is finished.  You need to make it work in a synchronous mode.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

  'Disable background updates
  SetBackgroundConnections False

  Sheets("Data").Unprotect
  ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
  Sheets("Data").Protect

  'Re-enable background updates
  SetBackgroundConnections True

End Sub

Private Sub SetBackgroundConnections(SetOn As Boolean)

  Dim cn As WorkbookConnection

  For Each cn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    cn.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = SetOn
  Next

  Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```